# Why is "a line to direction of (a,b)" $bx-ay$?

Tags: geometry

My lecture notes consider:

$$0=a u_x+b u_y=Du \cdot (a,b)$$

The line equation that satisfies this is:

$$bx-ay=c$$

Why?

Comment: What is the slope of a line in the direction of $(a,b)$? What is the slope of the line $bx-ay=c$?

Comment: @rogerl Yea of course it's this simple. What confused me is whether the line equation can be directly read from the $a u_x + bu_y$. Actually it can, because of the $Du \cdot (a,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your equation in the form
$$y=\frac{b}{a}x-\frac{c}{a}$$ then is $$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{b}{a}$$ if $$a\neq 0$$

Comment: Yea of course it's this simple. What confused me is whether the line equation can be directly read from the $au_x+bu_y$. Actually it can, because of the directional derivative $Du⋅(a,b)$.